# toDF is not a member of Seq, getting this error in Databricks notebook

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to create empty DF based on a case class and am trying to do that in Databricks notebook. But if I am doing that using object/class then getting error and if I take out the object defination then it runs successfully. Is this a bug in databricks notebook or I need to import anything.
Please suggest.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession 
object Emp {
   lazy val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
   import spark.implicits._
   def emptyDf {
   case class Employee(Name: String, Age: Integer, Address: String)
   var empDf = Seq.empty[Employee].toDF()
 }
}

--Error Message    
command-1113195242149456:9: error: value toDF is not a member of Seq[Employee]
         var empDf = Seq.empty[Employee].toDF()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to fix the problem by just moving the case class outside the def.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
object Emp {
  lazy val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._
  case class Employee(Name: String, Age: Integer, Address: String)
  def emptyDf {
     var empDf = Seq.empty[Employee].toDF()
  }
}
```

Note: Add teh case classes outside of the object defination, otherwise it will throw error when you call methods of the object.